# how to delete from postgresql database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postman

```
let total = req.body.Details.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  db.query('INSERT INTO position(unit,fulltime,user_id) values($1,$2,$3)'[req.body.Details[i].unit,req.body.Details[i].fulltime,companyuser.rows[0]._id],function(err,data){
    if (err) return callback(new Error(err));
    console.log('added')                            
  }) 
}
```

here I am able to insert the array values into the database, the array looks like:

```
"Details":[{"unit":"pqr","fulltime":"true"},{"unit":"abc","fulltime":"false"},{"unit":"xyz","fulltime":"true"}]
```

And it is from postman.

```
let total = req.body.Details.length;
for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
 db.query('DELETE FROM position WHERE unit != ($1) AND user_id = $2',[req.body.Details[i].unit, companyuser.rows[0]._id],function(err,data){
  if (err) return callback(new Error(err));
  console.log('deleted')                            
 }) 
}
```

And while updating, if I update `unit` only to `abc` like `"Details":[{"unit":"abc"}]` then `prq and xyz` need to be deleted from the database. But this delete query is deleting only `pqr` where am I wrong??

Comment: The `DELETE` query may be failing because `user_id` is not being matched in the `WHERE` clause. Where is `companyuser.rows[0]._id` coming from?

Comment: `    db.query('UPDATE companyUser SET "accessgroup_id" = $2,active = $3 WHERE _id = $1 RETURNING *', [query, data.companyUser.accessgroup_id, data.companyUser.active], function(err, companyuser) `

Comment: it is coming from here

Comment: the `!=` is checking only last value of array

Comment: Use `!=` only if you want to compare against a scalar (single) value. Use `NOT IN ...` to compare against values in an array. Your query `DELETE FROM position WHERE id != (?)` is potentially ambiguous.